# Error in code: Modern APIs with FastAPI and Python Course - Async web scaper

Tags: python, fastapi

Below is the python code (program.py) and the requirements file (requirements.txt).

Function async def get_title_range() is not working properly, it generates the following error code:

> httpx.HTTPStatusError: Redirect response '301 Moved Permanently' for
> url 'https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/271' Redirect location:
> 'https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/271/unlock-the-mysteries-of-time-pythons-datetime-that-is'
> For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/301

Python code, based on python 3.9 (program.py):

```
import asyncio
import datetime

import httpx
import bs4
from colorama import Fore

global loop
    
async def get_html(episode_number: int) -> str:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + f"Getting HTML for episode {episode_number}", flush=True)

    url = f"https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/{episode_number}"

    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        resp = await client.get(url)
        resp.raise_for_status()

        return resp.text


def get_title(html: str, episode_number: int) -> str:
    print(Fore.CYAN + f"Getting TITLE for episode {episode_number}", flush=True)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    header = soup.select_one('h1')
    if not header:
        return "MISSING"

    return header.text.strip()


def main():
    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()

    global loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_title_range())

    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
    print(f"Done in {dt.total_seconds():.2f} sec.")

async def get_title_range()
    tasks = []
    for n in range(270, 280):
        tasks.append((n, loop.create_task(get_html(n))))

    for n, t in tasks:
        html = await t
        title = get_title(html, n)
        print(Fore.WHITE + f"Title found: {title}", flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The requirements (requitements.txt):

```
bs4
colorama
httpx
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. It's the same error getting repeated, please reduce it down to a single request that reproduces a single instance of the error (it seems you have a loop somewhere). Basically the error is saying that calls to 'https://talkpython.fm/<id>' is now getting redirected to 'https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/<id>/...' and your code has no proper handling for it.

Comment: That link to the training requires an account. Which is why SO's [mcve] guide requires sharing the code that reproduces the error _in the question itself_, not behind a link.

Comment: Thanks for helping Gino. But the talkpython.fm/NUMBER redirects are public. Only some of the content on the training domain is account limited.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly enable redirects in `httpx` (unlike in `requests`). [From their docs](https://www.python-httpx.org/compatibility/#redirects):

*Unlike requests, HTTPX does not follow redirects by default.*

*We differ in behaviour here because auto-redirects can easily mask unnecessary network calls being made.*

*You can still enable behaviour to automatically follow redirects, but you need to do so explicitly...*

```py
response = client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)
```

*Or else instantiate a client, with redirect following enabled by default...*

```py
client = httpx.Client(follow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, solved by using:   response = client.get(url, follow_redirects=True)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code using request-html ASyncHtmlSession in Fast api

```py
@app.get('/')
async def ScrapeData(pages:Optional[int]= 1):
    crawle = Crawler()
    for page in range(1,pages+1):
        url = f"url here"
        asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
        r = await asession.get(url)
        await r.html.arender(sleep=1)
        widget = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="widgetContent"]')[0]
        items = widget.find('div')
        crawle.GetData(items)
    return crawle.data
```